# django compressor slower response time

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-compressor

I am trying to measure response using page load time chrome extension of django app with and without django compressor (by setting COMPRESS_ENABLED to True/False). I did clear browser cache, shutdown/start VM to make sure each test has a same and fresh condition. I also press F12 / Network tab on browser to see number of requests and KB transfer. For each test, I run several different pages and note down the metrics. While it is true that django-compressor enabled shows fewer number of HTTP requests, it appears to me that it has higher page load time than django-compressor disabled.

I understand that with django-compressor enabled, the page might run a bit slower initially as it needs to merge, compress js/css files and write compressed files to S3. But in the test I performed, compressed files are already available in S3 and there were no change in js/css files, thus the overhead of django-compressor is supposed to be minimal.

Anyone has similar issue and if there is setting to make django-compressor faster please advise. Thanks.

Comment: you may want to look here: https://github.com/django-compressor/django-compressor/issues/168

Comment: You're not listing where the page is specifically slower (JS? CSS? Images?) just saying it is slower in total. I mention this because CSS I worked on recently has URLs to background images but with compress enabled, those URLs get a "?<id>" appended. The "?" means the browser can not cache the result, which is a Bad Idea. I haven't got to the bottom of this nor found a reliable way to resolve it yet. FWIW